# If Item status = "Completed" >> Show QR code which open PDF inside SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have a Power Apps which integrates with SharePoint, and i am trying to implement the following:-

1. If the Item Status is set to "Completed" >> a PDF file will be generated >> saved to SharePoint Document library.
2. Inside the Power Apps form >> a QR code should be shown >> and when scanned the PDF file should open.

So can i implement the QR code functionality inside Power Apps ? and how?
Thanks